# How to know if my code is Inlined?

Tags: c#

I want to know if my code can and is Inlined or not.
I have found a way to do this, which is:

Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);

But i am not sure how it´s supposed to tell me.
If i use it on this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
internal static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
{
    Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToList().Find(delegate(ImageCodecInfo codec)
    {
        return codec.FormatID == format.Guid;
    });
}
```

What is the Console suppose to write if it´s inlined?
From my understanding, it´s supposed to write the name of the caller, for example:

```
Private void Caller()
 {

ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(bmpFormat)
 }
```

Console will then write Caller.

Is this correct?
If so, then nothing i have tried it on is inlined.

Comment: You would have to examine the actual IL in the assembly to determine if a method is inlined.

Comment: That doesn´t tell me much, can you be more detailed?

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceats605.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Isn't inlining always performed by the JIT compiler, not the C# compiler?

Comment: @dtb: Ah, I think you're right.  You would have to disassemble the actual binary code to identify inlining.  Totally not worth it under any reasonable scenario, IMO.

Comment: Really, well that sucks. I would love to know if certain methods are inline or not. Cause if they aren´t, i need to move them and inline manually (at least for certain things).

Comment: Have you done some measurements with a profiler and *specifically identified method calls as a performance problem?*

Comment: Yes i have, and certain stuff are Alot slower. Though those are at very small scales (fast calculations).

Comment: But, it it possible to call AggressiveInlining on everything?
Instead of writing it on every method?

Comment: Use `unsafe` code blocks for those calculations.  The overhead for a method call is very minimal, and if your loop is that tight already, just inline the code from the method yourself.

Comment: You *do not* want to inline everything.  Measure your performance with a profiler, and inline only those calls that are going to make a significant difference in performance.

Comment: Should i call unsafe, even when it´s safe code?
Really?
Isn´t Inline faster, always?

And well, for the method i am thinking about, it isn´t small, i prefer to have it in a seperate class.  And about profiling, the problem is, i can´t use it. It says "no launchable projects", and i don´t find any way to fix that:(

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "premature optimization?"  Seriously, you should not be worrying about inlining.  In 99 percent of cases, *inlining is not going to make any difference in the performance of your application.*  The JIT is smart enough to make that decision for you when it does matter.

Comment: Yes, but i am not trying to optimize just for fun. But well anyway, my question is answered, it´s not possible without looking at binary code and disassemble etc, which isn´t something for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GetCurrentMethod prevents inlining (Source http://prdlxvm0001.codify.net/pipermail/ozdotnet/2011-March/009085.html)

Keep in mind that inlining is done during JIT, not compilation.

Comment: Oh, guessed they "fixed" that. And yes, well i use Release mode